# Excel formula mutiple condition on more one row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I looking for the formula for column A (TRUE or FALSE). I check if column "C" contain "ERROR" text. Row number 2 (cell "C2") contain "ERROR" word, so the formula put "TRUE" in column "A". For now I have a formula per line: **=ESTNUM(CHERCHE("ERROR";$C2))** in french or **=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ERROR";$C2))**

```
FALSE    DPS-14    OK

TRUE     DPS-14    ERROR

FALSE    DPS-15    OK

FALSE    DPS-14    OK
```

**I want add a condition to my formula.** If a element from column "B" have a "TRUE" on column "A" then change (to "TRUE") for all same element. DPS-14 (row 2 is TRUE), also put "TRUE" on row 1 dans 3 because row 1, 2 and 3 are the same value on column "B".

```
TRUE     DPS-14    OK

TRUE     DPS-14    ERROR

FALSE    DPS-15    OK

TRUE     DPS-14    OK
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an `Or()` statement in there?

Comment: @BruceWayne, I think using a Or() but with what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this with a quick COUNTIFS.

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$5, B2, $C$2:$C$5, "ERROR") > 0
```

[Here's a Picture!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7TIm.png)

Basically, it just takes the current value on the line you're on, checks through the whole range for other values like itself, and then counts the number of ERROR's associated with that value. If it's greater than zero, you've got an error in at least one spot, so the record has an error.

There's a second easy option. If you can sort your data, sort first by the ID, then by whether or not it's an Error or OK (Descending). Then, if you call an index/match on the OK/ERROR column, and it's ERROR, you know it needs to be bool TRUE for all records.

[That looks like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoJ8n.png)

I know that in your data, that column doesn't literally say ERROR, so you'll need to modify this to either make a helper column to extract which records have ERROR values, or use an array formula with your other formulas. I'd recommend option 1, as it is a higher performance solution and more likely to be understood by other people looking at your work.

Comment: Solution with COUNTIFS is OK!! but the solution with INDEX and MATCH is KO if the order is different ("ERROR" not on the 1st)

Comment: Joe, if I want change ="ERROR" by contain "ERROR: ..." is possible?

Comment: Joe, I use you help in my solution but I still have a little problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419476/excel-formula-mutiple-condition-on-more-one-row-on-conditional-formatting

Comment: For your first comment, you'll want to sort first by ID and then by ERROR (so you put the error line on the top). For the second, it looks like you want to use a wildcard match but you appear to have everything figured out - nice job!

Comment: I can sort the file (prohibited in my case). The final solution is finished on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419476/excel-formula-mutiple-condition-on-more-one-row-on-conditional-formatting.