# Excel formula mutiple condition on more one row on conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want apply the conditional formatting on Column "A", "B", "C" and "D". I use this formula: **=NB.SI.ENS($A:$A;A1;$E:$E; "ERROR") > 0** in french or this formula for English: =COUNTIFS($A:$A, A1, $E:$E, "ERROR") > 0

[image]

I add in configuration: apply to =$A:$D

[image]

I want apply the conditional formatting on Column "A", "B", "C" and "D" but the result is only on Column "A".

[image]

I have 2 questions:

- Think you have to change the formula or change the configuration of
  the conditional formatting?
- If I want change **=**"ERROR" by **contain** "ERROR: ..." is
  possible?

[MY EXCEL FILE IS HERE](http://wikisend.com/download/514242/stackoverflow40419476.xlsx)

Comment: Please may you tell me *by words* what you mean with your 1st condition (i. e. what you consider as an *incorrect* value in the column `A`?

Comment: @MarianD, If a element from column "A" have a "ERROR*" on column "E"  for all same element. DPS-14 (row 2 is Error), also put "color" on row 1 and 3 because row 1, 2 and 3 are the same value on column "A". You can download the Excel file on http://wikisend.com/download/514242/stackoverflow40419476.xlsx

Comment: Merci! Upvote for your question and for @Xodrow answer, too. I learned some new things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salut !

Replace the formula with :

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$E:$E,"ERROR*")>0
```

In French:

```
=NB.SI.ENS($A:$A;$A1;$E:$E;"ERROR*")>0
```

2nd argument = $A1, not A1. "ERROR*" counts all cells beginning with "ERROR".

Comment: I change "ERROR" by "ERROR*" and I solve my second question. thanks. Have you an idea for the first question (apply the conditional formatting on Column "A", "B", "C" and "D")?

Comment: Yes, replace A1 with $A1 in the second parameter of NB.SI.ENS. See the formula in my answer.